# Can a vSphere host run in Azure?

Tags: azure, vmware, vsphere

I need to move two vSphere servers (running on physical servers - NOT VMs) that manage some local ESX servers AND some more ESX servers in remote offices nearby.

One vSphere server is vmWare v4.1, the other is version 5.1 (to match the managed ESX/VM clusters supported by them)

The office hosting both vsSphere servers is closing. The rest of that office's servers are all moving to Microsoft Azure in that region. The remote offices need to keep running their local ESX installations. They will however need a "new" vSphere overseer.

Can I also move the vSphere servers from the soon-to-be-closed office into Azure?

Does vSphere 4.1 or 5.1 as an application have any dependencies that a Hyper-V VM within Azure could not satisfy? I know vSphere can be run in a vmWare VM.

N.B. I am asking specifically about the vSphere "app", not whether vmWare VMs can be migrated to Azure. I have already found your good answers to that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for the vendor. Not a specific programming question.